# Why laravel 5.7 basic route redirect to 404?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

i have install fresh laravel 5.7. now when i declare route in web.php. when i declare like

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

it redirect to 404 page but.. when i declare my root directory name along with route just like

```
Route::get('blog/foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

it shows me expected result..

but i don't want to define like that. i want to define like this and get the expected result

```
  Route::get('foo', function () {
        return 'Hello World';
    });
```

help me !

Comment: replace 'foo' with '/foo' and check it

Comment: no it doesn't work.. and i also checked it before..

Comment: Are you using wamp or the built-in server with using the command `php artisan serve`? When I went from laravel 4 to 5, that was my biggest issue

Comment: Please can you show you're whole routes file and also the urls that you're using?

Comment: somehow it has been solved this.. i just made new installation by using "laravel new blog" and installed xampp again.. I really don't how it solved but somehow it solved.. thank you guys.. for all of your support..

Comment: Either route cache or server issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work perfectly fine but try the following command and let me know if it fixes your issue

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

There should be a route like `/{someParam}`
move your route `'/foo'` up so it is placed above param `/{someparam}` route